# Geo Spatial query - Elastic search using the NEST (.NET) API

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We have an index with a GeoShape field that contains boundaries of counties in WKT format such as MULTIPOLYGON (((-9.50189821688122 51.6790656404768, -9.52975113548365 51.6846028881403, -9.49436480898325 51.7002020861983, -9.501898216881 etc. etc.

We also have an index that has properties each with a Lat/Lng co-ordinates in another index.

How can we find which properties are within a particular county using the NEST syntax

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is the same question as: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/geo-spatial-query-using-nest-version-7-to-query-wkt-field/196673

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks again